# Checking for dictionary key based on dictionary values in a sentence

Tags: python, dictionary, nlp

I have a dictionary where values correspond to words and their keys correspond to categories for those words. I want to check whether these words/values exist in a sentence, if yes return category/key else return 'other' as a category.

As there are number of categories, the code should be capable of checking values for keys over each sentence in a loop.

I have written something, but not getting a output. I know this is not correct but I am stuck here.

```py
for i in data:
    if dictio.values() in i:
        print (dictio.keys())
```

In the above code I am just printing the categories, but I want a function that will return key for values matched in sentence.

My data is:

```py
data = ["my web portal is not working","online is better than offline", "i like going to pharmacy shop for medicines", 
       "web is the future", "i love apple"]
```

my dictionary is:

```py
dictio = {'fruits':['apple'], 'web': ['web', 'online']}
```

So the code should check (web/online/apple) in sentences and return key/category as output i.e. (Web/Fruits)

With this code I am getting output : ['web', 'web', 'web', 'fruits']

```
matches[]
for string in data:
   for category, words in dictio.items():
       for word in words:
           if word in string:
               matches.append(category)
               break
print(matches)
```

Comment: Consider making an example so it'll be more understandable, please.

Comment: I have added the example. Does this help?

Comment: Can you add how is the format of your output ?

Comment: There is no particular format, it can be list of categories like [web,web,other,web,fruits]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
data = [
    "my web portal is not working",
    "online is better than offline",
    "i like going to pharmacy shop for medicines",
    "web is the future",
    "i love apple"
]
dictio = {
    'fruits': ['apple'],
    'web': [
        'web',
        'online'
    ]
}
matches = []
status = True

for string in data:
    status = True
    for key, values in dictio.items():
        for value in values:
            if value in string:
                matches.append(key)
                status = False
                break
    if status:
        matches.append('other')

print(matches)
```

Output:

```py
['web', 'web', 'other', 'web', 'fruits']
```

Comment: Yes I have tried this, I want output [web,web,other,web,fruits]

Comment: @anant please check it now, I updated the code and the output is similar to your one.

Comment: m getting output 'other' only

Comment: I updated again @anant, please check it again, just print the value --> `print(matches)`

Comment: Got the right output. Thanks. I was wondering can we get the same output with else in place of status. I have made some but getting output : ['web', 'web', 'web', 'fruits', 'others']. Also can you explain for my understanding whats 'status' is doing here

Comment: Your'e welcome @anant. I updated few things in code, please check it. I use the `status` variable to append 'others' into the list. Because we have to loop all the values in `dictio` dictionary. If any value match with the item of `data`, we just append `key` value to the list and anything doesn't match mean our `status` is `True'. Earlier I put `status` in wrong place, now it's working fine without popping anything in the list. Inside two for loops looping and try find any matches value, otherwise add 'other` and move into the next sentence. Please ask anything, I'm happy to help you!

Comment: Thanks a lot @Kushan. Its very informative. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

```
data = ["my web portal is not working","online is better than offline", "i like going to pharmacy shop for medicines", "web is the future", "i love apple"]
dictio = {'fruits':['apple'], 'web': ['web', 'online']}


for string in data: # iterate over each string
    matches = [] # Create a list to store the matches for this string

    for category, words in dictio.items(): #iterate over the keys/values to check each
        for word in words: # For each word
            if word in string: # Check if it appears in the string
                matches.append(category) #If it does then add the category to the matches
                break # Break to only add each category once at most

    print(matches) # print results
```

output:

```
['web']
['web']
[]
['web']
['fruits']
```

more concise and 'pythonic'

```
for string in data: # iterate over each string
    matches = [] # Create a list to store the matches for this string

    for category, words in dictio.items(): #iterate over the keys/values to check each
        matches += set([category for word in words if word in string]) #Set will remove duplicates

    print(matches) # print results
```

Comment: This is giving only ['fruits'] as output whereas the output should be [web,web,other,web,fruits]

Comment: Explain why, what logic? Do you think you could change it to do that?

Comment: I have changed and now getting output ['web', 'web', 'web', 'fruits']. I think I am making some mistake but dont know what. I am sorry but how to show the changes code here

Comment: Did that please check

Comment: You need to explain better what exactly you want to be output.

Comment: I want output : ['web', 'web', 'other', 'web', 'fruits']

Comment: Explain how you want to come to that, what logic produces this result?

Comment: Your second code worked for me and got the right output. Just first code didnt gave the same output. Thanks for help